# Page_Load firing when following link to another page asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET, I've been reading a few questions related to this but I'm still unable to figure out what's wrong with my code, I have a default.aspx page with a menu on top created using a list (ul and li items) and putting the `<a href="">` tag to create the links to other pages but after following a link to another page, the Page_Load event fires before leaving the page, I understand this would be the expected behavior with Response.Redirect, but I don't know how to avoid this using  tags (if possible), this is the markup I'm using for the Default.aspx page:

```
<ul id="lista">
    <li><a href="Default.aspx"><strong>Inicio</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="Items.aspx"><strong>Item</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="IKs.aspx"><strong>IK</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Acerca de</strong></a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is the code behind I have for Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ExcelUtility excel = new ExcelUtility();
        dtDefault = excel.LeerExcel();
        gridResults.DataSource = dtDefault;
        gridResults.DataBind();
        gridResults.VirtualItemCount = dtDefault.Rows.Count;
    }
}
```

Basically, what I want to do is to follow the link to some other page without loading the default page before leaving, hope I make myself clear!

**Edit:** The root cause of this was having the default `<form runat="server">` tag at the beginning of the body section, this was causing the Page_Load event firing again in the same page once the links were being clicked, placing the hyperlinks outside of the form tag did the trick.

Comment: have you read up on what PostBacks are and the how and why things happen in postbacks.. whenever a page is called it's Page_Load event will be triggered.. so not really sure what you are trying to do

Comment: Hi MethodMan, yes, I've read about postbacks, but I don't see how this is related to hyperlinks, if I'm in the Default.aspx page and I want to go to Items.aspx then the Default.aspx's Page_Load method is executed before requesting the Items.aspx page, I want to avoid this and just go to Items.aspx

Comment: if you read up on postbacks and you understand redirects then you will understand my comment..

Comment: Simple HTML hyperlinks shouldn't fire `Page_Load` event. Is your HTML code wrapped into some custom control which has the attribute `runat="server"`??

Comment: Yes, they're inside the <form> tag created by ASP.NET

Comment: Well, that was it! the <form> tag was causing this, I need to play with it a little bit to make it work as I want, thanks a lot @ChandanRoy for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Kindly accept the answer, it will be helpful for the community. You should edit your question and post the root cause there as well. @julio.np

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code should be inside some HTML tag or custom ASP control which contains the attribute `runat="server"`. This is supposed to fire a `PostBack` request to the server.